# These days, what are good reasons for setting thread affinity rather than leaving it to the OS?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduling, affinity

Searching answers here for "thread affinity", I see a lot of interest in doing it but little justification for it save possibly getting stable QueryPerformanceTimer results.

Assuming a modern OS and a modern 2-4 socket workstation/server class machine with modern 4-6 core CPUs, what good reasons would anyone have for thinking they know better than their OS's scheduler ?  Are there any real world situations where taking more control of thead affinity is the right thing to do ?  What sort of performance benefits can be demonstrated ?

The last time I saw a really good case for setting thread affinity somewhere (as in, it was backed up by concrete results showing genuine and significant improvements in system performance), it was some obscure thing to do with Win2K device drivers.  But I haven't seen anything like that in years so when someone tells me they need to control thread affinity (but not why) these days I am deeply sceptical... but curious to be shown otherwise.

Comment: Hyperthreading,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300701.aspx#S11  It is back in i7.

Comment: OK, good point: back in the "bad old days" of non-hyperthreading-aware OS on hyperthreaded CPUs  it was certainly wise to e.g make sure two threads of your app didn't end up running hyperthreaded on one physical core, while the core "next door" sat there underutilised.  But OSs are wise about HT these days and don't let this happen.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason is if you have something that depends *heavily* upon caching. The OS scheduler doesn't necessarily take that into account to the degree you might like.

Comment: So what sort of percentage performance difference could I expect to see from controlling affinity in such an app vs. the uncontrolled, leave it to the OS case ?  I'm not entirely convinced by these caching arguments; caches can either be turned over in a minuscule fraction of the OS scheduler quantum, or are shared between cores.  Maybe on a multi-socket machine ?

Comment: @timday: The largest improvement I've seen personally was just under 2:1 improvement -- but that was a pretty unusual case. For every one that improves at all, there have probably been at least five that I couldn't improve at all, or couldn't even get as good of performance as leaving it to the OS (and of course that still only includes those where I *thought* I might be able to do some good).

Answer (score 1):

I use it to assign threads to cores; for example in a simulation you do the physics entirely on one core, and allow the rest of the computation to be executed on another one. It makes sense to be able to control this, if you're on a tight environment where you know the hardware.

Of course, configuring this needs to be done per system, so by default I let the OS decide the cores on which to run, but keep the option of restricting core usage.

Comment: Do you have concrete evidence (ie quantitative measurements) of the benefits of doing this ?  (e.g runtimes with and without controlling thread affinity).

Answer (score 1):

In the OS kernel and sometimes in kernel mode drivers you need to perform the same action on every CPU (e.g. update a system register). You can do that in a loop in a single thread, changing the affinity on each iteration.

Comment: Good example; I have seen code like this myself (it was actually buggy: it ran on the main thread and failed to restore all-CPU affinity after it was done, with the consequence that a subsequent bit of code which expected to spawn threads to all CPUs was limited to running them all on one CPU!  Ouch!).  I was thinking more of general performance issues than this sort of hardware specific thing though.

Answer (score 0):

For desktops it's quite unnecessary.

But I can see some applications where it would help. For example the CPU cache likes it if the app that runs on it doesn't change.

Another possibility is you have a critical task - you give it an entire CPU, and the other tasks use the rest of the CPUs.

Or the opposite: You have some low priority tasks, you put them all on one CPU, then leave the others free for more important tasks (using process priority will give you most of this benefit without having affinity, but I can imagine some memory heavy cases where it wouldn't).

Comment: As with the comments on other questions: quantitative evidence please!  I'm also very dubious about using thread affinity as a substitute for the OS's own scheduler's priority system (a use case which is in fact related to discussions which prompted this question).  In fact I notice Windows programmers seem to have a great deal of distrust of Window's process/priority mechanisms (which seems to be rooted in experiences back in the NT4/Win2K days) and always seem quite keen to impose "DIY" solutions using thread affinity or inter-thread signalling mechanisms.  Linux programmers trust their OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree its best to leave to the CPU to figure this out in most situations. However, the most common reason to go for thread affinity as far as I have seen is when you need good cache dependency. In multiple CPU systems, when a particular CPU caches something individually for itself and if the same thing has been cached in some other CPU, then I believe it can automatically get invalidated on the other CPU. So if a particular thread keeps changing CPUs on which it executes, then the cache hit rate will be too less. So in this case I guess it makes sense for the programmer to be a better judge of the COU affinities.
I also think the above point by Ariel about making sure a critical task constantly gets a CPU without throttling other low priority processes also makes sense.