# How can I change the default processor affinity in Linux?

Tags: linux, affinity

I want to run a number of benchmarks on a multi-core system running Linux.  I want to reserve one of the cores for my benchmarks.  I know that I can use `sched_setaffinity` to limit my benchmarks to that core.  How can I keep all other processes *off* my core?  In other words, how can I set the default affinity of all processes to not include my core?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you keep all the other processes off your "reserved for benchmarking" core, bear in mind that you can't stop them from consuming a variable and unpredictable proportion of the limited memory bandwidth to a multi-core chip, and that you can't stop them making variable demands on the shared L2 and L3 caches.

IMHO reproducible, scientific benchmarking needs a machine all to itself.

Comment: This is a dedicated machine running nothing but my benchmarks.  However, I'm unfamiliar enough with Linux and familiar enough with Windows to know that there are a few dozen system processes running in the background over which I have little control. I am trying to minimize their impact.

Comment: Ah I see; OK I was assuming you were trying to ringfence some resource on your desktop.  But personally I'd attack the problem using scheduling priority instead; just run your benchmarking process at higher priority than those system processes.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957687/these-days-what-are-good-reasons-for-setting-thread-affinity-rather-than-leavin particularly my comment on Ariel's answer.